# Does z-index affect the height of a div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bit of a puzzle on my hands. I have a div that should contain some images. The images aren't floating - I've got them in there using display: inline-block. The images have some z-index properties because on hover I dim the opacity of the image and display some text and a button.

And yet, the div that should contain the images just isn't altering its heigh to adjust to its content. I am completely stumped as to why this is. Adjusting the height property will adjust the size of the section, but it won't automatically adjust to contain the images, even though they're children of the div....

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

I've included part of my html and css.

```
<div class="second-section">
  <div class="outfitcontainer">
    <div class="outfit">
      <img src="purelyoutfit6.png" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay">
      <p class="price">$350 <span class="oldprice">$4200</span></p>
      <p class="item">FURR COAT</p>
      <p class="designer">Antonio Marras</p>
      <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-getit">GET IT</button></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="outfitcontainer">
    <div class="outfit">
      <img src="purelyoutfit7.png" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay">
      <p class="price">$350 <span class="oldprice">$4200</span></p>
      <p class="item">FURR COAT</p>
      <p class="designer">Antonio Marras</p>
      <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-getit">GET IT</button></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.outfitcontainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.outfit img {
  display: inline-block;
}

.outfit, .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  left: 0;
}

.outfit {
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: white;
}
.outfitcontainer:hover .outfit {
  opacity: .5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.outfit:hover + .overlay{
  z-index: 50;
}
.overlay:hover {
  z-index: 50;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.overlay p {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  line-height: 50%;
}
.overlay p:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 50%
}
.price, .item {
  font-family: "Brandon Grotesque Medium";
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #000000;
  line-height: 25%;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
.oldprice {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #383838;
  font-size: .75em;
  line-height: 25%;
}
.designer {
  font-family: "Didot Light Italic";
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #000000;
  line-height: 25%;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
.second-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 50;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the jsfiddle of what I think you want: http://jsfiddle.net/vvc93jfr/

Basically, the reason why your two boxes was no longer inside the black background was because you had your outfit and overlay set as `position: absolute;`

You only want the overlay to have a position of absolute. The rest would be just setting its top/left to where you want the overlay to be.

You also have a lot of random styles that you might want to clean up.

Ultimately, z-index does not affect the height of a div. It only affects the z-axis. Think about it as a stack of paper and looking at that stack in a birds eye view. You only see the paper at the top. That piece of paper would essentially have a z-index that's considered the highest (ex. 3424242134). The sheets below it would have a lower z-index.

Answer (score 4):

z-index doesn't affect the height of a div.

height of .second-section is 80% - what's the parents height?
If you set the parents height properly it should be fine.

In addition you might want to change from height to min-height - to make sure the images are shown completely in case they're bigger than the height you've set.